# read properties of undefined (reading 'app')

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:64319/lujnI6UYeBo=
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')
    at Object.app$ [as app] (http://localhost:49682/packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart.lib.js:37:101)
    at initializeApp (http://localhost:49682/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:87:25)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40666:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40697:7)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:49682/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:80:20)
    at initializeApp (http://localhost:49682/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:106:59)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40666:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40697:7)
    at Function.initializeApp (http://localhost:49682/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:105:20)
    at new main.MyApp.new (http://localhost:49682/packages/fupro/main.dart.lib.js:152:52)
    at main$ (http://localhost:49682/packages/fupro/main.dart.lib.js:169:20)
    at main (http://localhost:49682/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:39:29)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40646:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40503:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35432:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:36017:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:36055:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35897:23)
    at http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35083:46
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40503:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35432:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:36017:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:36055:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35897:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:35920:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40808:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:40814:13)
    at http://localhost:49682/dart_sdk.js:36279:9
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9104?uri=http://127.0.0.1:64319/lujnI6UYeBo=
```

Comment: It seems to be issue with Firebase_core_web package or initializing firebase app for web.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: What version of firebase SDK are you using? Copy the `firebase src` line in index.html

Comment: i am working on app not on web

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn the basics and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Do some research,search for related topics on SO; 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing firebase script line in index.html to
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>`. [Reference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/)

Comment: i am working on app not on web.so please tell me solution related to app

Comment: You are running your app in chrome?